# How can we have coalition government under majoritarian representation

Tags: proportional-representation, coalition

I am having some confusions between the 4 terms: majoritarian representation, proportional representation, single-party government, and coalition government. As I understand, in a majoritarian representation, a candidate that wins the election wins all the seat. Then how can coalition government happens?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you apparently suspect coalition government is possible in a majoritarian system? Just from skimming the Wikipedia articles I'm not all sure that's the case. So the answer may simply be "we can't" / "it doesn't".

Comment: You need to clarify your terminology. "Majoritarian representation" is not a word, I think what you mean is "majoritarian voting system".

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a candidate that wins the election wins all the seat". Do you mean that "the political party that wins the election wins more than half of the seats"? Or do you mean "a candidate that wins the election in his/her constituency wins mroe than half of the votes"? Please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

If a voting system is both truely majoritarian and operates in a single district, then coalitions can only arise if elected members can defect from their original party. However, if winners are selected from multiple voting districts/constituencies, then even if each individual contest is majoritarian (i.e. all winners from a district are from a single party) it's still possible that no party will have an overall majority in the legislative body, which could lead to a need for coalition government to actually do things.

As a (near) example, Greater London in the UK is divided into 32 boroughs, each of which has its own elected council. Councillors are elected from subdivisions called wards, with two or three councillors per ward. Elections are run using [block voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurality_block_voting), with each voter selcting candidates equal to the number of open seats on a single ballot paper (usually from a single party), and the three candidate with most votes being elected. In Havering the [2022 election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2022_Havering_London_Borough_Council_election) had results of

- 23 Conservative councillors
- 21 Havering Residents Association (HRA) councillors
- 9 Labour councillors
- 2 Independents

The HRA and Labour now govern [under a power sharing agreement](https://www.romfordrecorder.co.uk/news/local-council/havering-form-hra-labour-administration-2022-8995900), replacing an HRA-conservative coalition. The only way this isn't a fully strict example is that block voting does still sometimes lead to split ticket voting, however it is certainly not proportional.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify your terminology:

1. **Majoritarian representation**: This term actually does not exist. I think what you are referring to is "[majoritarian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system#Majoritarian_systems)", a principle in which if you receive more than half (>50%) of the votes then you win. This is usually used in the context of single-member constituencies under [FPTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-past-the-post_voting) or [instant runoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting).
2. **Proportional representation**: An electoral system where the amount of seats distributed between political parties is proportional to the number of votes they receive. This system tends to produce multi-party systems as it is very rare for political parties to win more than half of the votes.
3. **Single-party government**: This term is usually used in the context of parliamentary system, where more than half of the seats in parliament are controlled by a single party. Thus, the party gets to control the executive by itself alone. This is very common in [Untied Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Commons_of_the_United_Kingdom) or countries that use the [Westminster system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_system).
4. **Coalition government**: This term refers to a situation in which no party has more than half of the seats in a legislature, so parties have to form alliances together to form a majority. In this situation, you are likely to see a government consisting of ministers from different parties. As you may imagine, this is more common in countries that use proportional representation.

I'm not sure what you mean by "in a majoritarian representation, a candidate that wins the election wins all the seat" since the terminology is confusing. Like I said before, "majoritarian representation" is not a word and "winning all (100%) the seats" seems highly unlikely.

If I take your question as: "In countries that use majoritarian voting systems, the winning party usually wins more than half of the seats in the legislature. So how can there be coalition government in this context?"

The answer is: "very rarely". Countries that use majoritarian voting systems tend to produce two dominant political parties. This means that it would take a lot of effort for a third party to win enough seats to force either one of the parties into coalition government.